# How can i check size of file using ContentLength before save as in server (MVC4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My error is `Maximum request length exceeded.`
I want file upload must be smaller than 2MB. Please help me to fix code bellow, thanks

my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var path = "~/Images/upload/";

            if (Request.Files["UpFile"] != null && Request.Files["UpFile"].ContentLength < 2048)
            {
                var upload = Request.Files["UpFile"];
                upload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path + upload.FileName));
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The size of file too big");
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to manage your maximum request length for reducing errors to minimum:
[Maximum request length exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)

I think it's a good practice to use try..catch when working with uploading files even if you have global exception handler.